# Why do forbidden directories return a 404 rather than 403? and does it matter?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I had set `Options -Indexes` in my .htaccess,
So when someone tries to access a folder, such as `domain.com/images/` the server won't allow it.

When I try to access such folder, I get this message:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /images/ on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

And the Title also says 403,
Yet in my server log, the error that is sent is only 404, nothing about 403.

Why isn't a 403 showing, and is that ok?

Comment: That means you are using `ErrorDocument` somewhere.

Comment: What's ErrorDocument? I'm on Managed VPS, so I didn't make any definition nor do I really know how to. Is this situation ok or should this be fixed?

Comment: You can read about `ErrorDocument` in Apache manual

Comment: Ok, I have read, but I can't find anywhere where `ErrorDocument` is being used in my .htaccess, but rather the opposite - If I insert `ErrorDocument 403 "message"`, only then the server would indeed return a 403. So I still don't understand (a) what causes the 404 (b) what is better to have (user/bot wise) - send a 403 since it's 403, or send this 404